# websocket-rails standalone mode running heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, websocket

I'm trying to run websocket app using rails module "websocket-rails" by standalone
mode on heroku. I ran the app in my local env but it seems not working on heroku.
It seems my app cannot reach websocket server.

I use redis for the websocket backend and the redis config does not show any errors.
Is there anything else I can check to investigate the fault? Or heroku does not
support standalone mode websocket?

If there is any document, I'll appreciate that.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just the setting of websocket server. I'm not sure this is the legit answer, but just specify the app uri for websocket server, it worked. I wrote the details [here](http://tgib23.github.io/blog/2014/10/30/deploy-rails-websocket-app-into-heroku/)